# Error in links within 'Projects' when I deploy my Hugo site on Github

Tags: hyperlink, github-pages, hugo

I deployed my Hugo website using the academic template. In the index.md files for projects section, there is an option to add a `url_code` or `url_pdf` for the code or pdf respectively of the project.

When I upload a proper link, say `www.google.com`, it works correctly on the local server but after hosting it to Github, the link somehow changes to `https://myname.github.io/www.google.com`, which throws an error when accessed.

How to resolve this?

[For clarity, I am referring to the following PDF button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY7sU.png)